# Show rows when at least one condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe something like this (note, OrderNumber is a calculated field for the number of unique orders that customerID has)

```
data = [[1, 1, 'Jacket'], [1, 2, 'T-Shirt'], [1, 3, 'Jumper'], [2, 1, 'T-Shirt'], [2, 2, 'Jacket']] 


    CustomerID  OrderNumber Category
0   1           1           Jacket
1   1           2           T-Shirt
2   1           3           Jumper
3   2           1           T-Shirt
4   2           2           Jacket
```

I only want to filter or mask and only show those customerID's who have met a condition on their first order.

Let's say their first order **must** be from category of Jacket. Something like:

```
df = df[(df["Category"] == 'Jacket') & (df["OrderNumber"] == 1)]
```

This code will obviously now **only** show those rows meeting these conditions, so I only see one row.

I would like to see three rows, one for each OrderNumber of the customer with CustomerID = 1, with the second customer being ignored as even though they have a Jacket in an order, it is when OrderNumber = 2.

I'm a bit stumped as to how to even approach this problem. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df[df['CustomerID'].isin(df[(df["Category"] == 'Jacket') & (df["OrderNumber"] == 1)]['CustomerID'])]
```